# Opencv failed to parse AVI

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, anaconda, opencv3.0

I've installed opencv3.1.0 through anaconda along with the ffmpeg package. opencv still gives

```
Failed to parse avi: index was not found
```

when I try to read an .avi file.
Is it possible to have .avi files work straight out of anaconda or do I have to compile everything manually (a process I have not have had much luck with so far).

Comment: You video file has no index, you should encode it properly. Often the index is missing when the file is truncated.

Comment: I figured that since it worked using vlc that the movie itself wasn't the issue. Ran the file through mencoder -forceidx input.avi -o output.avi -oac copy -ovc copy and that did fix it.